# C++ Get Module size after DLL injection

Tags: c++, windows

I am creating a dll and when I inject the dll I need the module size of the process in which I injected the dll. How can I do this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "module size"?

Answer (score 0):

`Winapi` `GetModuleInformation` function will help you. Read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683201(v=vs.85).aspx)